# Using ctypes to overwrite an accessable struct from a library

Tags: python, memory, struct, ctypes

I want to use a C-library in Python, I use ctypes to do that.

I defined the struct that I want to access in the library, I want to create multiple instances of these structs in my Python program and overwrite the struct in the C-library with one of the instances, let it calculate and then overwrite it with another one from the instances.
Basically I want overwrite the *fields* of the struct thats linked to the library with other parameters without having to change every parameter by hand.

Example:

```
from ctypes import *

class Example(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("One", c_uint8),
                ("Two", c_double),
                ("Three", c_double)]


lib = cdll['./test.dll']
libInit = lib['init']
libStep = lib['step']
libClose = lib['close']

libInit()

In1 = Example
In1.One = 2
In1.Two = 10
In1.Three = 23

In2 = Example
In2.One = 3
In2.Two = 4
In2.Three = 50

In = Example.in_dll(lib, "Example")
In = In1

libStep()

Out = Example.in_dll(lib, "Example")

In = In2

libStep()

Out = Example.in_dll(lib, "Example")

libClose()
```

I know that overwriting the In parameter like I did it in the example doesn't work, because it removes the link to the C-library. Is there a way to overwrite it in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create some helpers in the Structure class.  You have to modify the `in_dll` variable but you can make it easier:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(push,1)
__declspec(dllexport) struct Example
{
    uint8_t One;
    double Two;
    double Three;
} Example;
#pragma pack(pop)

__declspec(dllexport) void libInit()
{
}

__declspec(dllexport) void libStep()
{
    Example.One += 1;
    Example.Two += 2;
    Example.Three += 3;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void libClose()
{
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *

class Example(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("One", c_uint8),
                ("Two", c_double),
                ("Three", c_double)]
    def set(self,a,b,c):
        self.One = a
        self.Two = b
        self.Three = c
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Example({},{},{})'.format(self.One,self.Two,self.Three)

lib = CDLL('test')

libInit = lib.libInit
libInit.argtypes = None
libInit.restype = None

libStep = lib.libStep
libStep.argtypes = None
libStep.restype = None

libClose = lib.libClose
libClose.argtypes = None
libClose.restype = None

example = Example.in_dll(lib,'Example')

libInit()
example.set(1,2,3)
print(example)
libStep()
print(example)
libStep()
print(example)
example.set(2,2,2)
libStep()
print(example)
libClose()
```

Output:

```
Example(1,2.0,3.0)
Example(2,4.0,6.0)
Example(3,6.0,9.0)
Example(3,4.0,5.0)
```

Comment: I have about 60 parameters which are individual for every struct and i have also about 30 different structs which have to be set as input before calculating. Is it possible to write some kind of helper which takes a struct as input and overwrites every parameter?

Comment: @Patrick Sure, just alter `def set` above to take the struct and assign all the parameters.